fast vs knapp vs gerade mal vs etwa vs ungefähr vs circa vs um die
Why is the answer to this question richtig?
Question:

Es hat ihm gefallen, Verantwortung für sein 50-köpfiges Team zu haben.

Transcript:

Thomas Hirschbaum: Ja, das kann man so sagen.
Nach dem BWL-Studium habe ich zuerst in der IT-Abteilung eines Logistikunternehmens gearbeitet.
Dann habe ich die Branche gewechselt und bin ziemlich schnell aufgestiegen - erst zum Teamleiter, dann zum Abteilungsleiter, Ich habe also eine ganz klassische Karriere im Management gemacht. Dabei war ich für viele innovative und spannende Projekte verantwortlich - und habe knapp 50 Mitarbeiterinnen und Mitarbeiter geführt.

“He enjoyed having responsibility for his almost 50-person (could be 48,49) team”. Doesn’t “knapp” mean below 50, not exactly 50?
Please help me understand the nuance differences between: fast, knapp, gerade mal, etwa, ungefähr, circa and um die.

Just to be clear, the "question" is really a statement and you're supposed to answer "richtig" or "falsch". And you're wondering why the answer key says "richtig" = "true" when it's a "sort of" at best. Is that correct? I'm thinking it's just a badly worded exercise and there's no actual issue with the German language.

Please check DWDS with many examples, similar words ...

“Ich habe es fast geschafft” - I almost made it. “Ich habe es knapp geschafft” - I barely made it. In this case, “fast” is failure, “knapp” is success.

The question is worded badly.
In the extract it's almost 50 and in the question it's exactly 50. It's not a good thing to do in an exercise book but things like this will happen in real life too. Out of convenience the speaker will omit a word which details the number of employees because it's "close enough". To the speaker the exact number is not the relevant information and he just rounds up.
About the words you need nuance for:
Fast and knapp tell you that a number is almost X but always below X.
Gerade Mal is exactly X but it conveys the feeling of the speaker that X is lower than what was expected.
The other ones (etwa, um die, circa, ungefähr) are all approximations. The number is close to X, it even can be X, but the speaker doesn't really know.

The simple part of the answer is: "ungefähr, circa, etwa, um die..." all mean the same thing (IMO). It says that the actual number may diverge a little bit, and in both directions.
The meaning of "knapp" is more difficult. DWDS (reading 6, https://www.dwds.de/wb/knapp#d-1-6) says "knapp" means "not entirely" ("nicht ganz"). I do not share this intuition. I think a statement "knapp 15 Minuten" is not wrong if it is exactly 15 min. This can be compared to uses like "der Rock ist aber knapp" (about a skirt) - it is either very short or too short. So in "knapp 15 Minuten", what you have may not be enough fo fill 15 minutes, but if it is just in the limit, this would be included. Just my feeling about it.
